# How can I migrate my photos from Lightroom 3 to Bibble 5?

Tags: lightroom, software, bibble

I used Lightroom for a while and edited some of my raw photos with it. Since Lightroom is non destructive the changes are not done to the raw images directly.

While using Windows and Linux I looked for a similar software to Lightroom and found Bibble 5 which can be used on both platforms.

The question is how can I migrate my photos including the editings from Lightroom 3 to Bibble 5.

The keywords / tags used in Lightroom aren't so imporant to migrate, because a have a good folder structure and can rebuild them easily, I just don't want to do the visual editings again for every photo.

I have about 700 photos in my Lightroom library (not that big) and they are all NEF (Nikon raw) files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there's currently no 'painless/seamless/automated' way to make the switch and **you will not be able to pull your files over with edits intact**. Your best bet will be to export anything you've made adjustments to as a 16 bit TIFF and then import them into your new chosen application. By keywording the files (with the keywords Adjusted, or Modified, perhaps) and generating sidecar files you will at least be able to sort them by keyword once you've got them out of Lightroom.

Obviously there's no way to know what products will be released in the future that have the potential to make the transition more seamless, but speaking as someone who spent a number of years in the software industry 'in another life,' my personal opinion is that I wouldn't hold my breath waiting, 'cause you will likely never see this transition be made any easier by Adobe... It's just not in the companies best interest or bottom line to make it easy to shift to a competing product, so there's just no real incentive to spend a lot of development time there...

Comment: Quite true -- the only way this is going to happen is if Bibble Labs implements it.

Comment: Lightroom 2 at least uses an SQLite data base which you can scrape for the development settings and transfer them to Bibble. Assuming that Bibble has either an API or another way of setting development settings. But a quick and dirty hack-job of such a thing might be possible in a weekend of coding.

Comment: So, I was curious enough about this that I went and checked it out.  A few data points: (1) Lightroom *does* store (at least some) "edits" in XMP files (if so configured), e.g. fields like `<crs:Exposure>+0.75</crs:Exposure>` inside an `xmlns:crs="http://ns.adobe.com/camera-raw-settings/1.0/` block; (2) bibble does, too, but (a) the filenames are different (appending `.xmp` instead of replacing the suffix (e.g. `.CR2`) with `.xmp`), and (b) the changes are different, e.g. `bopt:sat="51"`, referencing  `xmlns:blay="http://www.bibblelabs.com/BibbleLayers/5.0/"`, and in a different structure.

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, even if one renames/copies the XMP file to the name that Bibble expects, it won't heed (and will remove) the Adobe-added adjustments, replacing them with its own (starting from scratch).  So, I believe this answer to be basically correct, that it would require either Bibble to update their software to honor Adobe's way of representing things, or a 3rd party to right a conversion utility.

Comment: 'Edits' in Lightroom parlance are stacked record of what changes were made to the file and the order they were made. In Lightroom it is possible to move back and forth within the editing stack, thereby undoing any changes that you may have made. What is stored in the XMP are the *results* of edits made in Lightroom, not the edits themselves.

Comment: It is a subtle point, but an important distinction because while it is true that a user could conceivably go in and 'unadjust' any adjustments made in another program... For some of the values that would be very easy, but for others (Temperature for example) it would be impossible to do without knowing what the *starting* value was... Information that is not stored in the XMP file.

Comment: Additionally, Adobe does a pretty good job of recognizing and displaying these XMP values across their product lines, there is no such guarantee of 3rd-party products being capable of reading them in, and in fact many 3rd-party products simply erase values they don't recognize and start from scratch, as you've discovered.

Comment: The implication being that in transferring to a 3rd-party product, the only data from the XMP file that is kept is the standard EXIF data as I have stated elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Bibble website](http://bibblelabs.com/products/bibble5/features/pro-lite.html) Bibble 5 supprts XMP files, if you set Lightroom to write changes to the XMP files that go next to the NEF files the changes should be in there.

Comment: That's a good hint. I'll try that!

Comment: Sorry, but that's simply wrong. XMP files don't store Lightroom edits, only standard EXIF data...

Comment: @Jay Lance Photography Have a read of: http://www.oreillynet.com/digitalmedia/blog/2007/04/xmp_sidecar_files_and_lightroo.html It states that XMP files DO store edits etc

Comment: No it doesn't state that. It states that the *Results* of edits are stored, not the edits themselves.

Comment: @jay-lance-photography: uhh, it says "the XMP sidecar files contain the metadata, keywords and adjustments made to an image". "adjustments", "edits"... Same thing different word? The article might be wrong, I don't know, but it sure does seem to *say* that something is stored there that seems relevant to the questioner. If that's wrong, or unhelpful for some other reason, please explain more? (I don't currently have LR handy to investigate for myself. [XMP is XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) though, so it should be easy to see *exactly* what *is* stored.)

Comment: @jay-lance-photography: I think you're incorrect about whether Adobe stores "edits" (if we agree on what that term means, which I'm unsure of) in the XMP files.  It definitely does.  However, not in a way that Bibble understands, so... it's kind of a moot point.  More info in comments added to [your answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9369/migrate-from-lightroom-3-to-bibble-5/9370#9370).

Comment: See my comments in my answer above. You're misusing the term 'edits' (as used and stored in Lightroom). I'm not debating the fact that the *results* of the edits made in Lightroom are stored in the XMP file, only the record of the edits themselves. Further (as you yourself discovered) the ability to *use* the stored data becomes sketchy the minute someone moves outside of the 'Adobe Ecosystem.' Some products do OK with it, but others (like Bibble) simply erase it and start over...